# it works but I still get an error message, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

My teacher wants us to take a string that was imputed and take a certain increment and pull out the characters at those increments. I have it working but I still get this error message:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 21
```

then it highlights the line of code `point = base.charAt(sum)`:
here is my entire code so that you can see what I am doing.

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class EveryOtherCharacter {
 public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
    String base = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter an increment: ");
    int index = input.nextInt();
    int a = base.length();
    int sum = 0;
    char point;
    if(index>a) {
        System.out.println("Invalid increment: "+index);
    }
    else {
        while (index<=a) {
        sum+=index;
        point = base.charAt(sum);
        System.out.print(point);
   }
   System.out.println();
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Java is 0 indexed (the first character of the `String` been at position `0` and the last been at `length - 1`), so `while (index<=a) {` should probably be `while (index<a) {`

Comment: It seems like you are getting the character that are out of array.length

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the condition of the `while` loop should be `sum < a`, not `index <= a`, because the last index of an array/string is `length-1`, and `sum` is the variable you are incrementing, not `index`.

Also, another problem is that after the last "legal" cycle, `index <= a` will return `true`, and then you are adding `index` to `sum` which will take it beyond the bounds of the string. You should implement it as such:

```
do {
    point = base.charAt(sum);
    System.out.println(point);
    sum += index;
} while(sum < a)
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to use a `do-while` loop, you can implement it like so with a `for` loop:

```
for(sum = 0 ; sum < a ; sum += index) {
    point = base.charAt(sum);
    System.out.println(point);
}
```

Comment: my teacher will take off points if I use a do while loop. is there any way to do this with a for loop?